# AJAX login not working in Internet Explorer

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, authentication

Oh joy, another thing IE apparently does poorly.

I say "working sporadically" in the title because I've actually been able to get the code to work in IE, but there have been times (without any code changes) where it hasn't worked, and apparently the same is true for one of my clients.

My interim solution was to tell him to "stop using IE," but in the meantime, I feel it's my duty to investigate.

**The problem:** 
The login process seems to churn for a bit and then halt, without throwing the error message that would typically accompany a bad username or password. This is in IE only (my version is IE9, but I can't guarantee this issue is confined to that version alone). The login works perfectly in all other tested browsers, including mobile ones.

### Javascript:

```
$('#login-box > form').submit(function(){
    $('#login-response').html("<img src='assets/images/wait.gif' height='32' />");
    var str = $(this).serialize();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'lib/check-login.php',
        data: str,
        cache: false,
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log(errorThrown + '\n' + textStatus);
        },
        success: function(msg) {
            var output = msg.split('|');
            var delay = 1600;
            if (output[0] == 'OK') {
                if (output[1] == '') { //no referrer, redirect to home page
                    window.location = home_page;
                }
                else { //referrer set, redirect back to referring page
                    console.log('saying referer');
                    //window.location = output[1].substring(1);
                    window.location = home_page;
                }
            }
            else {
                $('#login-response').html('no, denied');
                $('#login-box input').val('');
                $('#login-box input#username').focus();
            }
        }
    });

    return false;
});
```

### PHP:

```
<?php
$sess = session_id();
if ($sess == '')
    session_start();

require_once('config.php');
try_login($_POST['username'], $_POST['password']);

/****** user has submitted credentials, check them and return value to javascript (AJAX) ***/
function try_login($u, $p) {
    global $mysqli;
    $res = $mysqli->query(' select u.user_id, u.user_name, u.user_pass, s.salt, ifnull(u.team_id,0) team_id
                            from users u left join seasoning s on u.user_id = s.user_id
                            where u.user_name = \'' . $mysqli->real_escape_string($u) . '\'
                            limit 1;') or die($mysqli->error);
    $row = $res->fetch_assoc();

    if($row['user_pass'] == crypt($p,$row['salt'])) {   //correct password, log user in
        if (isset($_POST['remember']))  //keep user logged in
            $duration = time()+60*60*24*365;
        else    //end user session when he closes browser
            $duration = false;

        $_SESSION['user_id'] = $row['user_id'];
        $_SESSION['team_id'] = $row['team_id'];

        $mysqli->query("update users
                        set
                            last_login = '" . date('Y-m-d H:i:s') . "',
                            login_qty = login_qty + 1
                        where user_id = " . $_SESSION['user_id'] . ";") or die($mysqli->error);

        $mysqli->query("insert into
                        activity (  activity_type_id,
                                    user_id)
                        values (8,
                                " . $_SESSION['user_id'] . ");") or die($mysqli->error);
        echo 'OK|' . $_SESSION['last_page'];
    }

    else { //login failed
        echo 'FAIL';
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: a few non-answer things: 1) you're using mysqli. you should be using prepared statements/placeholders, not manually escaping. 2) you're doing ajax requests, php should be returning json-encoded data, not custom string formats you have to parse yourself. 3) as for the hanging, it happens on occasion, since you ARE dealing with a network resource. browsers will occasionlly sit and spin for "no reason", then work perfectly once you restart the request.

Comment: @MarcB I agree on not using mysqli, but this code is from before I became acquainted with PDO, so forgive me. :) Hey, at least I *do* escape my query variables! As for point #3, trust me, I've tried this enough times to know that IE fails more often than it succeeds, whereas other browsers *never* fail, so I consider this a failing of IE, not some occasional snag I have to accept.

Comment: nothing wrong with mysqli. I'm just saying that you should be using prepared statements instead. they're the recommended going-forward tech to use, rather than manually escaping/building queries.

Comment: @MarcB: Well, PDO is faster than mysqli, but I get what you're saying about prepared statements. Like I said, this code predates my comfort level with anything other than the `->query()...while(->fetch())` method. :)  Any thoughts on an actual solution to the problem, while we're here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you shouldn't use

```
console.log
```

It's just for debugging purpose not for error on production code. It's an heisenbug on IE.
If removing the console.log doesn't resolve your issue, you can maybe do something like that (I know it's not really nice, but it can do the trick):

```
$('#login-box > form').submit(function(){
    $('#login-response').html("<img src='assets/images/wait.gif' height='32' />");
    var str = $(this).serialize();
    var errorNb=0;
    var xhr={
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'lib/check-login.php',
        data: str,
        cache: false,
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            errorNb++;
            if(errorNb<10)//to prevent infinite loop
                    $.ajax(xhr);
        },
        success: function(msg) {
            //your success code here
        }
    };
    $.ajax(xhr);
};
```

Comment: THANK YOU. That was driving me crazy. Ironic that the very code I use to debug was the code causing the issues. I was right after all: it was IE's fault. Enjoy your bonus 50 rep points!

Comment: Thanks a lot. Never thought that Console.log could be the issue.

Answer (score -1):

I would say don't blame IE until you know what the problem is. Here the problem is that you are submitting the form and making the ajax request. So sometimes it will work sometimes it wont, depending on the network speed.

The Fix:

```
$('#login-box > form').submit(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
...your code.


// or
return false;
}
```

Comment: I was under the impression the `return false` at the end of my code was synonymous with `e.preventDefault()`. Is it not redundant to have them both?

Comment: thats why i said "or". Plus i saw neither of them in your code

Comment: Sorry, it's in there, I just didn't catch it on the copy/paste. At any rate, adding `e.preventDefault()` didn't help either unfortunately.